# How do I increase the "buffer depth" of the run command in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, run-dialog

I use the <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> combo a lot to run commands and open paths. How can I increase the "buffer" of that selection box, or provide a longer history to select through? Is there a third party replacement that will hijack that same <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> command so I can do this through some other mechanism?

Answer (score 4):

You can't increase the MRU (Most Recently Used) list past 26 entries because Windows uses a letter to keep track of them in the registry, and the English language only has 26 letters. :)

As for a replacement, while product recommendations are generally off-topic, here's a couple you can check out for yourself to see if they fit the bill (never used either personally):

- [SlickRun](http://www.bayden.com/SlickRun/)

> SlickRun is a free floating command line utility for Windows.

[SlickRun and Win+R](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGetSlickRunToActivateWithWindowsR.aspx)

- [Executor](http://www.executor.dk/)

> This is a multi purpose launcher and a more advanced and customizable version of Windows' run.

[Executor and Win+R](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/22/a-windows-run-replacement/)